# Copy folder and file structure but copy all files as null?

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with tons of files and folders in it.

I want to make an exact copy of those folders and files but I want all the files to contain no data after being copied. I want them to be null. I want them to have the same name and folder structure as before but be as if I created a new empty file with that name and extension.

How can i do this using batch scripts or a tool of some kind. I know i could do it using C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found exactly what I needed.

```
Robocopy sourcedir destdir /S /E /CREATE
```

thanks anyways!